# SQL Server 2000: Ideas for performing concatenation aggregation subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, aggregate, concatenation, string-concatenation

i have a query that returns rows that i want, e.g.

```
QuestionID  QuestionTitle  UpVotes  DownVotes  
==========  =============  =======  =========  
2142075     Win32: Cre...        0          0  
2232727     Win32: How...        2          0  
1870139     Wondows Ae...       12          0
```

Now i want to have a **column** returned, that contains a comma separated list of "*Authors*" (e.g. original poster and editors). e.g.:

```
QuestionID  QuestionTitle  UpVotes  DownVotes  Authors
==========  =============  =======  =========  ==========
2142075     Win32: Cre...        0          0  Ian Boyd  
2232727     Win32: How...        2          0  Ian Boyd, roygbiv
1870139     Wondows Ae...       12          0  Ian Boyd, Aaron Klotz, Jason Diller, danbystrom
```

### Faking It

SQL Server 2000 does not have a `CONCAT(AuthorName, ', ')` aggregation operation, i've been faking it - performing simple sub-selects for the `TOP 1` author, and the author count.

```
QuestionID  QuestionTitle  UpVotes  DownVotes  FirstAuthor  AuthorCount  
==========  =============  =======  =========  ===========  =========== 
2142075     Win32: Cre...        0          0  Ian Boyd               1 
2232727     Win32: How...        2          0  Ian Boyd               2
1870139     Wondows Ae...       12          0  Ian Boyd               3
```

If there is more than one author, then i show the user an ellipses ("…"), to indicate there is more than one. e.g. the user would see:

```
QuestionID  QuestionTitle  UpVotes  DownVotes  Authors
==========  =============  =======  =========  ==========
2142075     Win32: Cre...        0          0  Ian Boyd
2232727     Win32: How...        2          0  Ian Boyd, …
1870139     Wondows Ae...       12          0  Ian Boyd, …
```

And that works well enough, since normally a *question* isn't edited - which means i'm supporting the 99% case perfectly, and the 1% case only half<strike>-assed</strike> as well.

### Threaded Re-query

As a more complicated, and bug-prone solution, i was thinking of iterating the displayed list, and spinning up a thread-pool worker thread for each "*question*" in the list, perform a query against the database to get the list of authors, then aggregating the list in memory. This would mean that the list fills first in the (native) application. Then i issue a few thousand individual queries afterwards.

But that would be horribly, horrendously, terribly, slow. Not to mention bug-riddled, since it will be thread work.

### Yeah yeah yeah

Adam Mechanic [says quite plainly](http://dataeducation.com/rowset-string-concatenation-which-method-is-best/):

> Don't concatenate rows into delimited
>   strings in SQL Server. Do it client
>   side.

Tell me how, and i'll do it.

### /cry

Can anyone think of a better solution, that is as fast (say...within an order of magnitude) than my original  "TOP 1 plus ellipses" solution?

For example, is there a way to return a results set, where reach row has an associated results set? So for each "master" row, i could get at a "detail" results set that contains the list.

### Code for best answer

[Cade's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410474/sql-server-2000-ideas-for-performing-concatenation-aggregation-subquery/2410524#2410524) link to [Adam Machanic's solution](http://dataeducation.com/rowset-string-concatenation-which-method-is-best/) i like the best. A user-defined function, that seems to operate via magic:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConcatAuthors(@QuestionID int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(8000)
    SET @Output = ''

    SELECT @Output =    CASE @Output 
                WHEN '' THEN AuthorName 
                ELSE @Output + ', ' + AuthorName 
                END
    FROM  (
        SELECT QuestionID, AuthorName, QuestionDate AS AuthorDate FROM Questions
        UNION
        SELECT QuestionID, EditorName, EditDate FROM QuestionEdits
    ) dt
    WHERE dt.QuestionID = @QuestionID
    ORDER BY AuthorDate

    RETURN @Output
END
```

With a T-SQL usage of:

```
SELECT QuestionID, QuestionTitle, UpVotes, DownVotes, dbo.ConcatAuthors(AuthorID)
FROM Questions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at these articles:

http://dataeducation.com/rowset-string-concatenation-which-method-is-best/

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/ (See Phil Factor's cross join solution in the responses - which will work in SQL Server 2000)

Obviously in SQL Server 2005, the FOR XML trick is easiest, most flexible and generally most performant.

As far as returning a rowset for each row, if you still want to do that for some reason, you can do that in a stored procedure, but the client will need to consume all the rows in the first rowset and then go to the next rowset and associate it with the first row in the first rowset, etc.  Your SP would need to open a cursor on the same set it returned as the first rowset and run multiple selects in sequence to generate all the child rowsets.  It's a technique I've done, but only where **ALL** the data actually was needed (for instance, in a fully-populated tree view).

And regardless of what people say, doing it client-side is often a very big waste of bandwidth, because returning all the rows and doing the looping and breaking in the client side means that huge number of identical columns are being transferred at the start of each row just to get the changing column at the end of the row.

Wherever you do it, it should be an **informed decision** based on **your** use case.

Comment: +1 for Adam Machanic's solution. And another +1 for you, sir, for mentioning the bandwidth cost in doing it "in client", giving many duplicated rows.

Comment: @Ian Boyd I did not realize that a FOR XML RAW solution will work in SQL Server 2000 - I would totally use that option.  I use FOR XML PATH all the time and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

I tried 3 approaches to this solution, the one posted here, activex scripting and UDF functions.

The most effective script (speed-wise) for me was bizzarely Axtive-X script running multiple queries to get the additioanl data to concat.

UDF took an average of 22 minutes to transform, the Subquery method (posted here) took around 5m and the activeX script took 4m30, much to my annoyance since this was the script I was hoping to ditch. I'll have to see if I can iron out a few more efficiencies elsewhere.

I think the extra 30s is used by the tempdb being used to store the data since my script requires an order by.

It should be noted that I am concatanating huge quantities of textual data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works in SQL Server 2000, but you can try it:

```
--combine parent and child, children are CSV onto parent row
CREATE TABLE #TableA (RowID int, Value1 varchar(5), Value2 varchar(5))
INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES (1,'aaaaa','A')
INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES (2,'bbbbb','B')
INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES (3,'ccccc','C')

CREATE TABLE #TableB (RowID int, TypeOf varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (1,'wood')
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (2,'wood')
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (2,'steel')
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (2,'rock')
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (3,'plastic')
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (3,'paper')


SELECT
    a.*,dt.CombinedValue
    FROM #TableA        a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                             c1.RowID
                                 ,STUFF(
                                          (SELECT
                                               ', ' + TypeOf
                                               FROM (SELECT
                                                         a.RowID,a.Value1,a.Value2,b.TypeOf
                                                         FROM #TableA                 a
                                                             LEFT OUTER JOIN #TableB  b ON a.RowID=b.RowID
                                                    ) c2
                                               WHERE c2.rowid=c1.rowid
                                               ORDER BY c1.RowID, TypeOf
                                               FOR XML PATH('') 
                                          )
                                          ,1,2, ''
                                       ) AS CombinedValue
                             FROM (SELECT
                                       a.RowID,a.Value1,a.Value2,b.TypeOf
                                       FROM #TableA                 a
                                           LEFT OUTER JOIN #TableB  b ON a.RowID=b.RowID
                                  ) c1
                             GROUP BY RowID
                        ) dt ON a.RowID=dt.RowID
```

OUTPUT from SQL Server 2005:

```
RowID       Value1 Value2 CombinedValue
----------- ------ ------ ------------------
1           aaaaa  A      wood
2           bbbbb  B      rock, steel, wood
3           ccccc  C      paper, plastic

(3 row(s) affected)
```

**EDIT** query that replaces FOR XML PATH with FOR XML RAW, so this should work on SQL Server 2000

```
SELECT
    a.*,dt.CombinedValue
    FROM #TableA        a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                             c1.RowID
                                 ,STUFF(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                                          (SELECT 
                                               ', ' + TypeOf as value
                                               FROM (SELECT
                                                         a.RowID,a.Value1,a.Value2,b.TypeOf
                                                         FROM #TableA                 a
                                                             LEFT OUTER JOIN #TableB  b ON a.RowID=b.RowID
                                                    ) c2
                                               WHERE c2.rowid=c1.rowid
                                               ORDER BY c1.RowID, TypeOf
                                               FOR XML RAW
                                          )
                                         ,'<row value="',''),'"/>','')
                                   , 1, 2, '') AS CombinedValue
                             FROM (SELECT
                                       a.RowID,a.Value1,a.Value2,b.TypeOf
                                       FROM #TableA                 a
                                           LEFT OUTER JOIN #TableB  b ON a.RowID=b.RowID
                                  ) c1
                             GROUP BY RowID
                        ) dt ON a.RowID=dt.RowID
```

OUTPUT, same as original query

Comment: @G Mastros, thanks, I've updated it with FOR XML RAW, which is supported by SQL Server 2000: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1077

Comment: Does not work on SQL Server 2000 because [FOR XML is not allowed in a subselect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226520(v=sql.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look to this [script](http://www.umachandar.com/technical/SQL6x70Scripts/Main44.htm). It's basically the cross join approach that Cade Roux also mentioned in his post.

The above approach looks very clean: you have to do a view first and secondly create a statement based on the values in the view. The second sql statement you can build dynamically in your code, so it should be straight forward to use.