# Combine fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

How to combine rows in SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [FOR XML RAW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410474/sql-server-2000-ideas-for-performing-concatenation-aggregation-subquery) in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: @learner: Not sure why you edited your original post to remove all of the details, but I'd be curious to see how you used XML RAW in a single query to achieve the output in the format you specified in your original question. Please post your solution.

Comment: @learner - could you reinstate your code or provide another example or post another question to see if we could help again?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user defined function to perform the string concatenation for each ID value.

```
create table t (id int,start varchar(100),finish varchar(100)) 
insert into t  
select 1,'Start_Main', '' union all  
select 1,'Start_Submain1', '' union all  
select 2,'Start_Main', '' union all  
select 2,'Start_Submain2', 'End_Submain2' union all  
select 2,'Start_Submain3', 'End_Submain3' union all 
select 2,'Start_Submain1', ''  union all 
select 2,'Start_Submain4', 'End_Submain4'   
Select * from t 
go

/* User Defined Function to perform string concatenation per ID */
create function udfStringConcat (@ID int)
returns varchar(500)
as
begin
    declare @x varchar(500)
    set @x = ''

    select @x = @x + t.start + ',' + case when t.finish <> '' then t.finish + ',' else t.finish end
        from t
        where t.id = @ID

    select @x = @x + 'End_Submain1,End_Main'

    return @x
end
go

select id, dbo.udfStringConcat(id)
    from t
    group by id
go

drop function udfStringConcat
drop table t
go
```

Comment: That is what I don't want to do. I want to do it in a single query(like for xml path() in sql 2005).