# Select multiple rows from SQL into one row in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I have query like:

```
DECLARE @razem VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  Ordering.orderID , 
        Document.number, 
        (User_info.name  +' '+ User_info.surname),   
        Ordering.dateStart, 
        Ordering.dateEnd ,   
        (
            select   COALESCE(' ',@razem)+sell_type.name as r  
            from    Ordering_sell_type, Sell_type 
            where   orderID = Ordering.orderID and 
                    Ordering_sell_type.sell_typeID = sell_type.sell_typeID
        ) podz
FROM    Ordering, User_info, Product_Document, Document, Document_type   
WHERE   Ordering.orderID = Product_document.orderID  
        AND Document.documentID = Document_type.documentID  
        AND Document.documentID = Product_document.documentID  
        AND  Ordering.userID = User_info.userID   
        AND Ordering.isClosed = 1 AND Document_type.typeID = 1   
GROUP   BY  Document.isitfiscal, Document.refDocID, 
            Document.number, Ordering.orderID, User_info.name, 
            User_info.surname, Ordering.dateStart, 
            Ordering.dateEnd , Ordering.isCLosed  
ORDER   BY Ordering.dateEnd
```

And in that COALESCE function I want to get all pay type for selected order - for example, orderID 123 have payTypes = Card, Cash, orderID have payTypes = Cash.

Problem is that I want to have it in one simply row as last row of main query, like:
orderID, Document.number, UserInfo.name+surname, dateStart, dateEnd, ->card, cash<-
but after trying query like above i got error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

because it returns more than one row. Is it possible, to get pay types in subquery and return as one string?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: In oracle: WM_CONCAT, LISTAGG or XMLAGG functions will turn multiple rows sharing similar data into a list.  Coalese only works one row at a time and doesn't combine rows.  [XMLpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005) in SQL server i believe does similar combinations; I think mySQL uses [Group_Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the syntax you have used, I am assuming you are using SQL-Server, and as such you can use SQL-Servers XML extension to concatenate strings.

```
SELECT  Ordering.orderID, 
        Document.number, 
        [UserName] = User_info.name  +' '+ User_info.surname,   
        Ordering.dateStart, 
        Ordering.dateEnd,
        [podz] = STUFF((    SELECT  DISTINCT ' ' + SellType.Name
                            FROM    Ordering_Sell_Type
                                    INNER JOIN Sell_Type
                                        ON Sell_Type.sell_typeID = Ordering_Sell_Type.sell_typeID
                            WHERE   Ordering.OrderID = Ordering_SellType.OrderId
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    Ordering
        INNER JOIN User_Info
            ON Ordering.UserID = User_Info.UserID
        INNER JOIN ProductDocument
            ON Ordering.OrderID = Product_Document.OrderID
        INNER JOIN Document
            ON Document.DocumentID = Product_Document.DocumentID
        INNER JOIN Document_Type
            ON Document_Type.DocumentID = Document.DocumentID
WHERE   Ordering.IsClosed = 1
AND     Document_Type.TypeID = 1
ORDER BY Ordering.dateEnd;
```

Note I have replaced all your ANSI 89 joins with ANSI 92, as this is the more modern syntax, and is [generally accepted](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) as the more legible option (I say generally accepted as it is of course personal preference and there are also still some cases when Oracle optimises ANSI89 joins better).

**EDIT**

Having seen your data the duplicates are from the Product_Document Table, you can remove these by using this:

```
SELECT  Ordering.orderID, 
        Document.number, 
        [UserName] = User_info.name  +' '+ User_info.surname,   
        Ordering.dateStart, 
        Ordering.dateEnd,
        [podz] = STUFF((    SELECT  DISTINCT ' ' + SellType.Name
                            FROM    Ordering_Sell_Type
                                    INNER JOIN Sell_Type
                                        ON Sell_Type.sell_typeID = Ordering_Sell_Type.sell_typeID
                            WHERE   Ordering.OrderID = Ordering_SellType.OrderId
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    Ordering
        INNER JOIN User_Info
            ON Ordering.UserID = User_Info.UserID
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  DISTINCT OrderID, DocumentID
            FROM    Product_Document
        ) Product_Document
            ON Ordering.OrderID = Product_Document.OrderID
        INNER JOIN Document
            ON Document.DocumentID = Product_Document.DocumentID
        INNER JOIN Document_Type
            ON Document_Type.DocumentID = Document.DocumentID
WHERE   Ordering.IsClosed = 1
AND     Document_Type.TypeID = 1
ORDER BY Ordering.dateEnd;
```

Comment: If I've not guessed the DBMS correctly there are a number of other methods answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791247/sql-server-possible-pivot-solution/10796492#10796492)

Comment: Where is the duplication coming from, are there multiple documents per order where the document type is 1?

Comment: No, there is only one document for each orders. Its like that, orders is only order when its not closed. after we close it (- the order) it becomes document (and it appears in Document table)

Comment: There is nothing really wrong with using DISTINCT on the query, but it is generally better to isolate the source of duplicates and deal with them there. A good way to find them would be to run the same query with `SELECT *` and see where you have varying values in rows where the columns listed above are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This SO article/answer does a good job of discussing different approaches to rolling-up/aggregating a series of varchar rows into a single column, like you are talking about https://stackoverflow.com/a/2410524/283895

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  But it depends on the RDBMS your using.

In order to generate a list of data in one row you must use an analytic function specific to the RDBMS your using, or write your own specific function.

In oracle: WM_CONCAT, LISTAGG or XMLAGG functions will turn multiple rows sharing similar data into a list.

Coalese only works one row at a time and doesn't combine rows.

- ORACLE: WM_CONCAT, LISTAGG, XMLAGG
- SQL SERVER: XMLpath
- My SQL: Group_Concat

Use/Syntax varies. so I suggest searching on those terms depending on your RDBMS.